# How to combine two window functions from scipy?

Tags: python, function, scipy, exponential

I'm trying to create a window function in scipy that combines a step function with an exponential window as given in scipy by scipy.signal.windows.exponential. The expected result should be
`f(x)=0 (0<x<a), =1 (a<x<b), = exponential (b<x<c)`

Is it possible to create a new window function by writing a new function (step function) and combining it with an existing scipy function (exponential).

Comment: What have you tried? The definition of the function you have in your question is pretty easy to build using `np.where`.

Comment: I defined a function manually that does the step function. I'm trying to combine it with the windows.exponential function. I couldn't figure out how to do that except try to append the results-which didn't work.

Comment: It would help if you posted the code that you have tried, along with any errors you see. Concatenating or appending several arrays is a good way to do this, given that you have non-overlapping ranges of input data.